# configure allowed_tcp_congestion_control via config files in linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, tcp

I am trying to come up with a custom set of TCP congestion control variants as part of the `tcp_allowed_congestion_control`. I do have multiple variants on my `tcp_available_congestion_control` list but not sure how I would add some of them to my allowed list.

I am aware we are able to change it in our installed kernel via `echo variant1 variant2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_allowed_congestion_control` but is there a way I could directly change this via the config files in the linux kernel source code.